# Attempting to construct a generic type in C# fails with MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, generics, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following class definition:

```
public abstract class ControllerBase<T, V> : Controller where T : EntityBase<T> where V : GenericRepository<T>
```

Then later on in the class I have the following code:

```
private V _repo;
...
_repo = (V)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(V), _dbC, _c);
```

This compiles just fine.  I then have a class with the following definition:

```
public class SecurityRoleController : ControllerBase<SecurityRole, GenericRepository<SecurityRole>>
```

That also compiles just fine.  However, when I try to hit /SecurityRole in my browser, I get an exception that `Constructor on type GenericRepository'1 not found`.  (Note that it's actually a backtick in the exception but that breaks SO formatting.)  This is despite the fact that `GenericRepository<T>` has a public constructor that works just fine when I try to directly create an instance of the class.

Anyone know how I can properly construct a generic instance of the class?

TIA,
Benjy

EDIT:

Constructor of `GenericRepository`:

```
public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext, Context c, string[] includes = null)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    _c = c;
    if (includes != null)
    {
        _includes = includes;
    }
    return;
}
```

And, the types of `_dbC` and `_c` are of `DbContext` and `Context`, the types that the `GenericRepository` requires in its constructor - and yes, I got these from `.GetType().FullName`.   Any thoughts?

Comment: When you say it has "a public constructor that works just fine" -- is it a public *parameterless* constructor?

Comment: No, it's a public constructor that takes the two arguments I'm passing it per the `Activator.CreateInstance` line above.  Sorry about that - good call.

Comment: Your code looks good.  Can you please post your constructor declaration and also the *exact* types (preferably by you outputting the result of `_dbC.GetType().FullName`) of `_dbC` and `_c`?

Comment: Show the constructor of `GenericRepository`.

Comment: Your repository needs a public parameterless constructor.  Change your where constraint clause for your GenericRepository to include "new()",  that way your compiler will stop you.

Comment: @KirkWoll - see above edits for answers to your questions (also @leppie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor declares three parameters.  But your call to `Activator.CreateInstance` is only passing two arguments -- it's not passing in a value for the last parameter (which possesses a default value -- `string[] includes = null`):

```
_repo = (V)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(V), _dbC, _c);
```

`CreateInstance` requires that all the parameters be specified -- it bases its method-overload resolution algorithm on the arguments you pass and does not take into account the possibility of default parameters.  Thus, to fix, just pass in `null` (the default value) as the last argument:

```
_repo = (V)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(V), _dbC, _c, null);
```

Comment: You are using a default parameter.  The compiler will re-write your code to new thing(..., null) and then compile that.  Since you aren't using the compiler's smarts, you need to do the work yourself.  That means passing in values for optional parameters, because they really aren't "optional" exception from a syntax point of view.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks so much for your help and for teaching me something new about the compiler!

Comment: @benjy, glad I could help.  Though to be pedantic, the compiler would have actually handled this scenario -- it's the *runtime* method overload resolution that is less sophisticated than the compile-time resolution. :)